# run time error 1004 application defined or object defined error (vba excel)

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub searchCMB_Click()
Dim ws
Dim OTr As Range
Dim Datework
Dim cl As Range
Set ws = Worksheets("PCMB")


    
    Set OTr = ws.Range("a3:a36").Find(Employeecm.Text, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
    
    
    Datework = day & "/" & month & "/" & years
    Set cl = ws.Range("c2:dc2").Find(what:=Datework, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
    
    If ws.Range(ws.Cells(OTr.Row, cl.Column)) <> "" Then
        Original = ws.Range(Cells(OTr.Row, cl.Column))
    Else
        MsgBox " Do not have OT "
    End If
    
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks to me like one of your `Find` calls returned nothing. You do not have a check for that before you try to use `OTr` and `cl`.

Comment: Before that line, add: `If OTr Is Nothing Or cl Is Nothing Then Stop` and see if it stops. Then check your variables.

Comment: I think you just want `ws.Cells(OTr.Row, cl.Column)` not `ws.Range(ws.Cells(OTr.Row, cl.Column))` in both that line and the subsequent one.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO -- something like this is what braX is suggesting. The code below isn't tested because we can't use your code to reproduce the error. In future try to post code that we can use to get the same error (i.e. no undefined variables, some sample data, etc)

```
Option Explicit 'make sure you have this

Private Sub searchCMB_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim OTr As Range, cl As Range, original As Range 'added definition of original. Make sure you have Option Explicit enabled so that you don't forget to dim variables
    Dim datework As String
    
    Set ws = Worksheets("PCMB")

    datework = day & "/" & month & "/" & years 'where are day/month/years coming from?
    Set OTr = ws.Range("a3:a36").Find(Employeecm.Text, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows) 'employeecm?
    Set cl = ws.Range("c2:dc2").Find(what:=datework, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
    If OTr Is Nothing Or cl Is Nothing Then
        'handle this scenario -- range(s) couldn't be found
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'I used intersection here instead. The variable "original" wasn't defined, so I made it a Range
    Set original = Application.Intersect(OTr.EntireRow, cl.EntireColumn) 'set the variable before testing its value to avoid duplicating the code
    
    If original.Value = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox " Do not have OT "
    End If

End Sub
```